# Mount google drive on command line using gvfs-google

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, cinnamon, gvfs, google-drive

Recently, Arch linux ships [gvfs-google](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/gvfs-google/) package in order to mount Google Drive using Gnome Online Accounts ([gvfs-goa](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/gvfs-goa/)). However, since I am using Cinnamon desktop rather than Gnome, it seems that this integration does not properly work.

As of now I used to sync Google Drive manually using [drive](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/drive/). Is there a way to mount Google Drive using gvfs-google on the command line?

Comment: Did you solve this?  I'm on XFCE.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install via pacman gnome-control-center and add your account from that Gnome component. Unfortunately, that means a ton of annoying Gnome dependencies come with this Gnome component to use the gvfs plugin for drive.

The other option is to install a bunch of ocaml dependencies with google-drive-ocamlfuse in AUR and go that route. I haven't been able to get google-drive-ocamlfuse to compile without creating soft link garbage on the filesystem.

Comment: According to [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/248) gnome-control-center should not run outside GNOME.

Answer (score 3):

```
gio mount google-drive://ondrej.holy@gmail.com
```

[GVFS Bug 796064 - impossible to mount](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=796064#c2)

Comment: Also useful for MTP devices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to mount it via GUI?
I believe you are looking for the `gvfs-mount` command.
I'm assuming that you already authenticated successfully.
When running `gvfs-mount --list`, you should get something like this:

```
Drive(0): ST1000DM003-1ER162
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  Volume(0): OS
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(1): HL-DT-ST DVD+/-RW GTA0N
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Volume(0): address@gmail.com
  Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGoa)
```

For mounting, try:

```
gvfs-mount google-drive://address@gmail.com/
```

And for unmounting:

```
gvfs-mount -u google-drive://address@gmail.com/
```

Both commands return no output on success.
For me, it mounts at:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=address/
```

Replace `address` with the correct address in the above commands.

Comment: I get "Invalid mount spec" when trying to mount using this command. And the manual is less than helpful about what is a valid mount spec…

Comment: It seems the address is case-sensitive. At least this triggered the "invalid mount spec" for me.